# Can't get to desktop

Tags: ubuntu, login, xfce, login-manager

After installing a base command line install of Ubuntu 10.04, I installed slim and xfce which worked fine for the first 2 or 3 reboots.  However, now when I start up, it gets to the slim login screen, I enter in my username and press enter, then I just get a black screen with a couple of random looking characters at the top left of the screen.

Why might this have started to happen?

Comment: Might be a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/slim/+bug/546292

Comment: look at your logs, kill slim then start it by hand.

Comment: If I install my system using `xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-video-vesa`, I get the problem described above, however, if I use just use `xserver-xorg-core` it installs all the video stuff.  So I think that means I am installing the wrong video section?  How do I find out which video section I need so I don't have to install all of them?

Answer (score 0):

Boot the system into single-user-mode if your computer has that feature, and do the command:

mount -uw /

Then, try deleting the slim files. If this doesn't work, then you will have to reinstall your operating system using single-user-mode. If you don't know what single-user-mode is, just google it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late, but does this help you?

[ubuntu-boots-to-black-screen-with-cursor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279976/ubuntu-boots-to-black-screen-with-cursor-after-upgrade-from-18-04-to-20-04/1279979#1279979)

(Copying from it - below)

---

Ok, so I would try to re-install the GUI / Desktop:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt autoremove

sudo apt remove ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

---